# Building a complex Laravel SQL query

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a rather complex problem.

First of all, here are my models:

1 ) TagsAdybooks

```
 <?php namespace App; use App\Livres; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use Auth; class tagsAdybooks extends Model {
public function getid()
{

    return $this->id;
}

/**
* Protège une table 
* @var string 
*/
protected $table = 'tags_adybooks';

 /**
 * Permet de voir quel champs sont modifiable
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
     'titre_fr','titre_en','slug_fr','slug_en','numero','principal','tags_adybooks_id'];

/**
*Annule la fonction create et update automatique
* @var bool
*/
public $timestamps = false;


 /*
* Liaison livres et Tags
*/
public function livres(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Livres::class,'livres_has_tags_adybooks');

}

public function livresTags(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Livres::class,'livres_has_tags_adybooks')->where('nouveaute','=',1)->where('actif','=',1)->whereHas('disponible',function ($query){
        $query->where('id','=',1);
    })->orderBy('id','desc');

}


public function livresOffice(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Livres::class,'livres_has_tags_adybooks')->where('date_office','desc')->get()->groupBy('date_office');
}

public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany( tagsAdybooks::class,'tags_adybooks_id','id')->orderBy('titre_'.\App::getLocale(),'asc')->has('livres');
}
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(tagsAdybooks::class,'tags_adybooks_id');
}
```

2 ) Livres :

```
<?php namespace App; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use Auth;use Cart; use Carbon\Carbon;  class Livres extends Model{
/**
* Protège une table 
* @var string 
*/
protected $table = 'livres';



 /**
 * Permet de voir quel champs sont modifiable
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
     'titre','sous_titre','description','photo','apercu','video','disponibilite','prix_ttc','prix_promo','langue',
    'isbn','ean_13','date_parution','date_office','format','prix_lancement','faconnage','nbre_page','typesID','collection','clil','nouveaute'];

/**
*Annule la fonction create et update automatique
* @var bool
*/
public $timestamps = false;
protected $casts = [
    'clil' => 'array',
];
/*
* Liaison like et livres :
*/
public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'like')->whereDeletedAt(null);
}
public function tagAdybooks(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(tagsAdybooks::class,'livres_has_tags_adybooks');
}
```

I would like them to select all the tagsadybooks that are main and have books or all the tagsadybooks that are main and their children have books

To do this, I tried a joint:  `$tags=tagsAdybooks:: join('livres_has_tags_adybooks', 'tags_adybooks.id', '=', 'livres_has_tags_adybooks.tags_adybooks_id')
            ->join('livres', 'livres_has_tags_adybooks.livres_id', '=', 'livres.id')
            ->select( 'tags_adybooks.*')->orderBy('titre_'.App::getLocale(),'asc')->where(function($q){
             $q->whereHas('livres');$q->orWhereHas('children');})->get();`

or another request : `$tags=tagsAdybooks::where('principal','=',1)->orderBy('titre_'.App::getLocale(),'asc')->whereHas('children')->has('livres')->get();`

Unfortunately, I get either the main tagsadybooks that have books or all the tagsadybooks but are not main. Can you give me a lead, please?

I would like to understand where my mistake is ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below query, I build a query with both.

```
tagsAdybooks:: join('livres_has_tags_adybooks', 'tags_adybooks.id', '=', 'livres_has_tags_adybooks.tags_adybooks_id')
        ->join('livres', 'livres_has_tags_adybooks.livres_id', '=', 'livres.id')
        ->select( 'tags_adybooks.*')
        ->orderBy('titre_'.App::getLocale(),'asc')
        ->where(function($q){
            $q->whereHas('livres');
            $q->orWhereHas('children');
         })
         ->orWhere(function($q){
            $q->where('principal','=',1)
            $q->whereHas('children')
            $q->has('livres')
         })
         ->get();
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. When I make your request. I get the mainAdybooks tags that have books and the non-main ones. I only get half of the desired result. :( I added a distinct one to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by changing my strategy.  Here is my solution:
`$principale=tagsAdybooks::where('principal','=',1)->orderBy('titre_'.App::getLocale(),'asc')->has('livres')->get();
        $nonprincipale= tagsAdybooks::where('principal','=',0)->orderBy('titre_'.App::getLocale(),'asc')->has('livres')->get()// $pole = Pole::where('slug','=',$poleSlug)->first();// $categories = $pole->listeCategories;         $tags= new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
        foreach ($nonprincipale as $categorie){
            $tags = $tags->push($categorie->parent);
            $tags= $tags->flatten()->unique('id');
        }
        $tags = $tags->merge($principale);
        $tags= $tags->flatten()->unique('id');`